# How to ge Nuxt.js render csp config to work?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, content-security-policy

My Nuxt.js app is running in `universal` mode on `localhost:4000` with a backend API that's running on `localhost:3000`.

I'm adding the following to my `nuxt.config.js`:

```
  render: {
    csp: {
      hashAlgorithm: 'sha256',
      addMeta: true,
      policies: {
        'default-src': ["'self'"],
        'script-src': ["'self'"],
        'style-src': ["'self'"],
        'connect-src': ["'self'", 'localhost:3000']
      }
    }
  },
```

But in Chrome console I get the following errors:

[image]

Comment: What have you found about this? I'm in a similar situation!

Comment: Yes, there isn't any documentation on it, but you're not supposed to use `addMeta: true`. I have no idea why it's an option, but without csp does work server-side.